# Why does pressing the Go on the android keyboard send two KeyEvents to onEditActionListener

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext, keyevent

I was just very curious as to why the onEditActionListener displayed two KeyEvents when I logged the events.

```
    pageNumET.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView t, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
            if(!(event == null)){
                Log.e("ACTIONID", actionId+"");
                Log.e("ACTIONEVENT", event+"");
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    infoText.setText("IT WORKED");

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

That is the code, it works fine.
Then when I press Go in the emulator.

This is Logged:

```
E/ACTIONID: 66
E/ACTIONEVENT: null
E/ACTIONID: 0
E/ACTIONEVENT: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x16, repeatCount=0, eventTime=427524, downTime=427524, deviceId=-1, source=0x0 }
```

I don't know why there was a second event.

Comment: Can you share xml layout with EditText?

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyup if you only want one event. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands).

Comment: Yeah, but I only used the EditorAction Listener - The emulator registers the Go click automatically - I don't think you can limit the EditorActionListener to only one event. It seems to just take whatever is sent to it.